# cant grab remote content but can view in browser

Tags: php

Seriously I confused with this problem.. I made a url shortener website and tried its API call.

So I put this script in one of my hosting

```
<?php 
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://klik.pw/api?api=BEHbDA19Z3e1&url=http://google.com");
echo $homepage; 
?>
```

I got blank page. I tried this script with my 3 different server and all the produce blank page..

Then I take out `http://klik.pw/api?api=BEHbDA19Z3e1&url=http://google.com` and open it in my browser, voila, it show me the output that I want to grab with the php code..

anyone know why my php cant grab the result but my browser can view it?

Then I tried to remove part of parameter in the url in the php script

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://klik.pw/api?api=BEHbDA19Z3e1");
echo $homepage;
?>
```

and it show me some error message asking for put "url" parameter.. why this happen??????

Comment: check the value of allow_url_fopen first and let us know the version of php you are using

Comment: `allow_url_fopen = On` and Im using **PHP 5.3.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CURL function

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
}

echo file_get_contents_curl("http://klik.pw/api?api=BEHbDA19Z3e1&url=http://google.com");
```

Comment: it works. btw, do you know why `file_get_contents` give me blank page?

Comment: You try comment out this line from my code and you will see the same error. 

    `//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');`

So, I believe URL shortening website must have a check for USERAGENT.